# jQuery/JS: Check for $_POST PHP variable and if it exists, call a jquery function to be executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post

Here's my problem:

- on my homepage I have a select box with city names. User chooses a value and then is taken to another (inner) page.
- that inner page has exactly the same select box with city names only in the case user opened it directly (ie. didn't come from homepage). That's because choosing a city is Step 1 in my search process.
- so, if the user accessed the inner page directly, he will choose a city, submit the form firing off a jquery script that searches based on that city value. The page layout changes but the address stays the same (jquery re-arranges the elements, showing filter options in the left column).
- in the case user arrived from homepage, i want the user to skip city selection on the inner page as he already chose it on the homepage.
- I'm using totalStorage plugin for capturing the homepage city value

Basically, I want to separate the two ways of accessing the inner page by checking isset($_POST['city-homepage']);
If false, user is accessing it directly so everything is fine.
if true, however, I need to immediately call that jquery function (search_workers()) and automatically set the value of my select box to be $.totalStorage('city') as that is what has been written to a cookie when the city was chosen on the homepage.

```
function searchWorkers(){
    var result=false;

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo $this->action("search_workers"); ?>",
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            city: $("select[name=city]").val(),
            help_wanted: $("#help_wanted").val(),
            gender: $("#gender").val()
        }
    }).done(function(msg){
        result=JSON.parse(msg);
    });
```

What is the best practice in doing what I want to do? I'm not very familiar with Javascript so please, have understanding if my question is silly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find a solution.

When user is on my homepage and selects a city, I store in a cookie (with $.totalStorage):
ref = 'home' AND city-hp = selected value
and then form's action takes him to the actual search page.

When he gets there, in a document ready function I check the ref variable for value 'home'. If true, I call my worker_search function and on the next line I set the ref variable to a new value (needed because from this point I don't need anything from the homepage).
If false (user didn't come from homepage but directly), I set ref to 'inner' and I don't call the function here because user is about to choose the city first.

In my function worker_search I then evaluate for ref again, and based on result I set the value of select#city:
if 'home', value of the above is set to city from cookie (that's what user chose on homepage)
if 'inner', value is set normally (according to what city user selected)

That way my worker_search function gets value for its select#city variable in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your PHP file check whether $_POST['city-homepage'] is set. If so, you should process that information and lay out the page accordingly. You also can have the php file set the selected city in the drop down.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['city-homepage'])) {
    //output the page with all the layout and information needed since the user
    //has selected the city already. And when creating the drop down box:
     echo '<select name="city" onchange="searchWorkers()">';
     foreach($cities as $city) {    // assuming $cities is an array containing
                                    // the name of each city in the list
     if($city==$_POST['city-homepage'])
          $selected='selected="selected"';
     echo '<option value="'.$city.'" '.$selected.'>'.$city.'</option>';
     $selected='';
        }
    }
    else {
       //display the page as though the user has not selected a city
      }
```

Comment: Bryan, thanks for replying. I was aware of your way but I needed a way to fire my jQuery function if a user came from homepage, as that value that has been carried over from homepage needs to be used in the function to retrieve the results.
Look below for my (own) answer how I solved it.